# Populating a list with all associated values for a common index?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tuples

I have a List(Of Tuple(Of Object, Double) that is populated as I run through my DataGridView of purchased parts by task. Each task is represented by a four-digit number. Most tasks are represented multiple times on the DataGridView becasue they require multiple parts for completion (but not all of them). For each of my Tuples in this list, Item1 is the task number and Item2 is the sum of the costs of each part required to complete it. Here is the code I have right now that populates the list.

```
Private Sub populateDoubleList()
    purchasedSum = New List(Of Tuple(Of Object, Double))
    For i = 1 To DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim allbyTask As Double = DataGridView.Item("TOTALCOST", i - 1).Value
        While DataGridView.Item("TASK", i).Value = DataGridView.Item("TASK", i - 1).Value
            allbyTask = allbyTask + DataGridView.Item("TOTALCOST", i).Value
            i = i + 1
        End While
        purchasedSum.Add(Tuple.Create(DataGridView.Item("TASK", i - 1).Value, allbyTask))
    Next
End Sub
```

There are about 70 tasks. This method only populates the List with 39 items. I know the code is wrong but I can't think of how to improve it or how to tell if a task has only one part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rereading the data from the `DataGridView`, you should probably just use the `DataSource` or wherever the data originally came from. Since we don't know what that is, I'll show some code that reads the `DataGridView`.

As you say the Task is represented by a four digit number, I have used an `Integer` rather than an `Object` to store it in. I have also used a `Dictionary(Of Integer, String)` to store the total cost for each task. That makes it easy to find the current total for each task.

```
Private purchasedSum As Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)

Private Sub populateDoubleList()
    purchasedSum = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim taskNum As Integer = CInt(DataGridView1.Item("TASK", i).Value)
        Dim cost As Double = CDbl(DataGridView1.Item("TOTALCOST", i - 1).Value)
        If purchasedSum.ContainsKey(taskNum) Then
            purchasedSum(taskNum) += cost
        Else
            purchasedSum.Add(taskNum, cost)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The DataSource is a DataTable populated by a SQL query. It's called dtPurchased.